# Is there a Pattern in Scala that add a method to an Array object?

Tags: class, scala, arrays, design-patterns, final

Is there a Pattern in Scala that can add a method to an Array object?

I am thinking of the implicit conversion of Int to RichInt.  But that can't be done as Array is a final class.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

As long as you avoid name collisions with any other implicit on `Array` (e.g. `ArrayOps` in 2.8, which adds the collections methods), you can extend using the normal implicit pimp-my-library pattern:

```
class FooArray[T](at: Array[T]) {
  def foo() = at.length*at.length
}
implicit def array2foo[T](at: Array[T]) = new FooArray(at)
scala> Array(1,2,3).foo
res2: Int = 9
```

Answer (score 6):

Implicit conversions are not prevented by the `final`-ness of the input class. `String`, for example, has an implicit conversion to `RichString` (Scala 2.7) or `StringOps` (Scala 2.8).

So you're free to define implicit conversions for `Array` *with one key caveat*: You must forgo Scala's built-in implicit conversion from `Array` to `ArrayOps` (in Scala 2.8 only).